# how to make activity output string to be another activity input string

Tags: android

I created two activity the first one toast string after function 
and second activity must take this string from first activity making it input in `TextView`

This is my first activity

```
package com.example.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

public class  AirportActivity extends Activity implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener, OnMarkerClickListener{    
    boolean markerClicked;
     PolylineOptions rectOptions;
     Polyline polyline;
      GoogleMap googleMap;
      List<LatLng> points;
     List<Polyline> polylines;
     String f = "" ;
      String[] placeNames = {"Cairo International Airport","Alexandria International Airport","Borg El Arab Airport",
                "Marsa Matrouh Airport","Sharm el-Sheikh International Airport","Taba International Airport","El Kharga Airport",
                "Assiut Airport","Luxor International Airport","Aswan International Airport","El Arish International Airport",
                "St. Catherine International Airport","Sharq Al-Owainat Airport","Abu Simbel Airport","Sohag International Airport",
                "Port Said Airport","El Tor Airport","Dakhla Oasis Airport","Marsa Alam International Airport","Cairo West Air Base","Almaza Air Force Base"};
         String[] placeNamesSnippet = {"Cairo International Airport1","Alexandria International Airport2","Borg El Arab Airport3", "Marsa Matrouh Airport4","Sharm el-Sheikh International Airport5","Taba International Airport6","El Kharga Airport7", "Assiut Airport8","Luxor International Airport9","Aswan International Airport10","El Arish International Airport11", "St. Catherine International Airport12","Sharq Al-Owainat Airport13","Abu Simbel Airport14","Sohag International Airport15", "Port Said Airport16","El Tor Airport17","Dakhla Oasis Airport18","Marsa Alam International Airpor19t","Cairo West Air Bas20e","Almaza Air Force Base21"};
         Double[] placeLatitude =  {30.111370, 31.192553, 30.917138,31.324435,27.978620,29.590988,27.188222,27.047695, 25.670264,
                23.960397,31.076449,28.684537,22.580600,22.375813,26.331926,31.281150,28.208842,25.688581,25.558141,
                30.116704,30.095975};
         Double[] placeLongitude = {31.413910, 29.953141,29.693375, 27.222200,34.393354,34.778946 , 33.800840, 31.013473 , 32.704063,
                32.821163,33.832256,34.062882, 28.720754, 31.611667,31.728437,32.242223,33.645257,28.972356,34.582821,
                30.916667,31.362748};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.airportactivity);

    googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.mapView)).getMap();
    //googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
//  googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    polylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
    setmap();


}   private void setmap()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i<21;i++)
      {
          googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                  .snippet(placeNamesSnippet[i])
                  .position(new LatLng(placeLatitude[i], placeLongitude[i]))
                  .title(placeNames[i]));

        points.add(new LatLng(placeLatitude[i], placeLongitude[i]));
      }
     markerClicked = false; 
      googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
      googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            points.add(arg0.getPosition());
            googleMap.clear();
            setmap();
             FindShortestPath();
              markerClicked = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
 }
public void dis (int[] p)
{
    double x = 0 ;
    double s= 0;
    int numOfNodes = points.size();
    for (int index = 0 ; index < numOfNodes-1 ; index++)
    {

    x  = distance2(points.get(p[index]).latitude,points.get(p[index]).longitude , points.get(p[index+1]).latitude,points.get(p[index+1]).longitude, 'K');
    s = s+x ;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Total distance of path  = " + s+"KM" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    f = String.valueOf(s); 
    }
        /*::  are available at http://www.geodatasource.com                          :*/
        /*::  Official Web site: http://www.geodatasource.com                        :*/

        private double distance2(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;

        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);

        dist = rad2deg(dist);

        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit == 'K') {

        dist = dist * 1.609344;

        } 
        return (dist);

        }

        /*::  This function converts decimal degrees to radians             :*/

        private double deg2rad(double deg) {

        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);

        }
        /*::  This function converts radians to decimal degrees             :*/
        /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
        private double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
        }

public void onClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent("net.learn2develop.MAIN"));
    }    
public static double distance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
    double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
    double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
    double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
    double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    return 6366000 * c;
}
// calculate distances matrix then get shortest path then call draw
public void FindShortestPath()
{
TSPNearestNeighbour tsp = new TSPNearestNeighbour();
int adjacencyMatrix[][] = new int[points.size()][];
int counter = 0,innerCounter ;
int[] result = new int[points.size()];

for(LatLng point : points)
{
    innerCounter=0;
    adjacencyMatrix[counter] = new int[points.size()];
    for(LatLng point1 : points)
    {
        if(point.equals(point1))
        {
            adjacencyMatrix[counter][innerCounter] =  0;
        }
        else 
            adjacencyMatrix[counter][innerCounter] =(int) distance(point,point1);
            innerCounter ++;
    }
    counter ++;
}
result = tsp.tsp(adjacencyMatrix);
DrawShortestPath(result);
dis(result);

}
//draws the shortest path with markers 
public void DrawShortestPath(int[] path)
{

    googleMap.clear();

int numOfNodes = points.size();
for(LatLng point : points)
{
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
               .position(point));
}
for (int index = 0 ; index < numOfNodes-1 ; index++)
{
     googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
.add(points.get(path[index]), points.get(path[index+1]))
.width(3)
.color(Color.RED));
}
}
class TSPNearestNeighbour
{
private int numberOfNodes;
private Stack<Integer> stack;

public TSPNearestNeighbour()
{
    stack = new Stack<Integer>();
}

public int[] tsp(int adjacencyMatrix[][])
{
    numberOfNodes = adjacencyMatrix[0].length ;
    int[] result = new int[adjacencyMatrix[0].length];
    int resultCounter = 1;
    int[] visited = new int[numberOfNodes];
    visited[0] = 1;
    stack.push(0);
    int element, dst = 0, i;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    boolean minFlag = false;
    result[0] = 0;

    //System.out.print(1 + "\t");

    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        element = stack.peek();
        i = 0;
        min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while (i < numberOfNodes)
        {
            if (adjacencyMatrix[element][i] > 1 && visited[i] == 0)
            {
                if (min > adjacencyMatrix[element][i])
                {
                    min = adjacencyMatrix[element][i];
                    dst = i;
                    minFlag = true;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (minFlag)
        {
            visited[dst] = 1;
            stack.push(dst);
            result[resultCounter] = dst;
            resultCounter++;
            //System.out.print(dst + "\t");
            minFlag = false;
            continue;
        }
        stack.pop();
    }
    return result;
}

}
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Note : the output " s " is double and i convert it to string

second activity

```
package com.example.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMS extends Activity 
{
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    AirportActivity air =  new AirportActivity();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        final TextView ltextview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        /*
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Content of the SMS goes here..."); 
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
        */
        ltextview.setText(air.f); 
        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {               
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                air.f = ltextview.getText().toString(); 

                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && air.f.length()>0)                
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, air.f);                
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }
    public String take(String s)
    {
        air.f = s;

        return air.f;

    }
    //---sends a SMS message to another device---
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {      
        /*
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, test.class), 0);                
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
        */

        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                      
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);               
    }    
}
```

What I must do to make word message to be the toast of the first activity?
sorry for bad english

Comment: So what you wan to do is to pass data from one activity to the another?

Comment: yes but the output of the first to be the input(Edittext) of the second 
i want when the second activity begin the edittext in the second initialized with this string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass data using Intents,
what you have to do is: create an Intent object and load it with you string as extra then start the new activity as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("ActivityA.this", "ActivityB.class");
intent.putExtra("key", "your string");
startActivity(intent);
```

in the second activity get the extras you already sent and do what ever you want with is:

```
String myString = getIntents().getExtras().getString("key");
```

notice that "key" is a key to your string value or you can think of it as mark that identifies your string from other extras, so you can name it to something related to the String.

you also visit http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html for more Info on Intents.